# Editing old questions should bump them?

Tags: discussion, edits, bump, serial-edits

Look at this:

[image]

A fellow decided to "curate" some old questions and now the feed is completely polluted with old questions that prob don't make anymore sense, since most of them are about a buggy patch of Minecraft...

Is that the desired behaviour? is there anything anyone can do?

Comment: Are you asking a general question about how editing and bumping work, or are you asking if this behavior by this user is what's desired?

Comment: @Leonardo - Arqade (Gaming SE) mod here - Thanks for the report, but in future you should consider posting questions like this to the site-specific meta (in this case, [Arqade Meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/)), unless you have a request or feature that could only be handled at the entire SE-network level. This one could be handled at the community level :)

Comment: @Robotnik tks! I did searched quickly for the meta-specific, but could find only this one... I thought perhaps they were all merged or something... Im not a "meta" kinda of guy if you know what I mean

Answer (score 14):

In general, the important thing is that edits are happening and that they're not being done in a way that's hidden so that no one is aware of them. The fact that an edit bumps a post is an important part of making sure that edit gets reviewed, so feel free to take a look and see if the edit was correct.

If a user were doing this en-masse and the posts *didn't* bump, they could do a ton of damage to the site with no one the wiser - that'd be much worse than a few hours of the home page being flooded.

In this specific case, the user made 17 edits - which is less than half of the 50 visible on the front page (if you view 50). So that's not as huge of a problem as it can be. Even in this specific case, I think the volume isn't too bad. But, feel free to check the per-site policy. Some sites have an expectation that big editing work be done in smaller chunks to avoid flooding the front page.

Some sites also request or suggest that major retagging events be done as part of a group effort to make sure that there's agreement in whether the retagging is appropriate.

Comment: FWIW 17 edits fills the homepage for anonymous/not logged in users (only see 15) so it is somewhat of a problem depending on how you look at it. This is why on SFF we have the 5 in 15 soft policy on edits on the homepage by one user.